# Netbeans + sqlite3 = Fail?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've decided to give Python a try on Netbeans. The problem so far is when try to run program *I know* works, i.e. if I ran it through the terminal. For the project I selected the correct Python version (2.6.5). And received the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/XXX/NetBeansProjects/NewPythonProject3/src/newpythonproject3.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       import sqlite3 ImportError: No module named sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Search for PYTHONPATH. You probably have different settings in your OS and Netbeans.